# How to use inline JavaScript in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, inline-code

Support that I have this hidden field:

```
<input type='hidden' id='handler' name='handler' value='5534882394' />
```

And imagine that I fetch an HTML fragment from server via jQuery AJAX.

```
<div id='result'>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

However, instead of writing something like this:

```
$(function(){
   $('#result span').text($('#handler').val());
});
```

I'd like to use something like:

```
<div id='result'>
    <span>javascript:$('#handler').val();</span>
</div>
```

However, I don't get the intended result. Can I use this approach with JavaScript?

**Update:** Everybody please, I know about `$(document).ready();`. So, don't provide better ways. I just wanted to know if it's possible to have inline JavaScript, or not, and if yeah, how?

Comment: If you're using Jquery, please **don't** use inline. You have better ways.

Comment: Why do you want to do it that way? What purpose does it serve?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you can't use that approach with Javascript. There is no such thing as inline Javascript.

What you see in a link like `<a href="javascript:alert(1)">` is the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol, similar in use to the `http:` protocol. When you point the browser to such an URL, the browser runs the script.

If you want to run a script in the page, you need a script tag.

Comment: Great answer @Guffa, you really deserve your high score buddy. :)

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 6):

You could do -

```
<input type="text" id="handler" value="yes"/>
<div id='result'>
    <span>
       <script>document.write($('#handler').val());</script>
    </span>
</div>
```

and the page would run the Javascript when it hit the script tag. You'd have to make sure that  '#handler' element was already loaded though or the script would fail.

In general it would be better to keep script tags such as this away from your mark-up.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/h6zXs/

Comment: That doesn't do what the OP wants.

Comment: That statement returns a string value, but that doesn't mean that that string will be put inside the SPAN element. SCRIPT elements are not replaced with the return value of their statements.

Answer (score 6):

Although the `<script>` tag works and would let you do what you are trying to do, I would really suggest rethinking your design there. This is not directly what you would call "unobtrusive Javascript".

Why do you prefer to mix HTML and JS? If it's for curiosity - OK, but if this is intended to turn into production code then you might want to separate the two as much as you can. You will be rewarded with a much better maintainability in the end.

Answer (score 3):

Have you forgotten about [the `<script>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTML/Element/Script)?

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script>$('#result').text($('#handler').val();</script>
```

Comment: thanks, but I said inline JavaScript. A JavaScript you use in `href` of an `a` element: `<a href='javascript:void(0);'></a>`. This doesn't require `<script>` tag.

Comment: so what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Script tags **are** inline JavaScript. Maybe you're looking for something more like http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.tmpl/.

Answer (score 2):

A few years back, I had that exact problem:  I was using AJAX to retrieve HTML and that HTML had embedded Javascript.  I was never able to find a better solution than parsing the HTML manually to dig out the Javascript tags and calling `eval` on their contents.  Hackish and unreliable, but it was the best I could find.